# Getting NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID for a custom view

Tags: android, kotlin

Steps to reproduce my problem

1. Create a custom view

```
class VideoTrimmerView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context) {
    private val backgroundPaint: Paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
    }
    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.draw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawRect(Rect(0, 0, width, height), backgroundPaint)
    }
}
```

2. Add `<declare-styleable>` resources to the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="VideoTrimmerView" />
</resources>
```

3. Add layout xml file `activity_video_trimmer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VideoTrimmerActivity">

    <com.udara.developer.myapp.videotrimmer.VideoTrimmerView
        android:id="@+id/video_trimmer_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/open_video_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Open Video"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

4. Enable view binding in module level `build.gradle`

```
android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

5. Use view bindings to access views

```
class VideoTrimmerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityVideoTrimmerBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityVideoTrimmerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)
    }
}
```

I get the following error when running the app

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: com.udara.developer.my_app:id/video_trimmer_view
```

The problem only happens when custom views are used. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you please also add the `activity_video_trimmer.xml` file here? Thanks

Comment: @ravi I updated the question. Added `activity_video_trimmer.xml`

Comment: I created sample app following above steps and getting the same exception at runtime. Here is the repository https://github.com/UdaraWanasinghe/ViewBindingCustomView

Comment: Bro... December 22 convacation thiyenawa ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have invoked super constructor without `attrs` parameter.

Previous constructor version

```
class VideoTrimmerView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context) {
}
```

After adding `attrs` parameter

```
class VideoTrimmerView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {
}
```

In the android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#subclassview) it just tells

> To allow `Android Studio` to interact with your view, at a minimum you must provide a constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet` object as parameters.

Now the problem is solved!